# Requisição HTTP (POST)

Tags: angular, http, post

Olá, estou estudando Angular e para treinar estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação Web, porém estou tendo problemas com o Post:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar? A mensagem de erro que aparece no navegador é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gustavo bem vindo ao stack overflow, por favor poste o codigo como texto de acordo com as normas do site

Comment: Tenta tirar o stringify na hora de enviar

Comment: Gustavo, não se esqueça de definir uma resposta válida para sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gustavo,

Certifique se que você tem um form.value válido e faça a requisição sem o Stringfy como o Eduardo mencionou. O ideal é que você utilize um objeto Game - assim como é feito no serviço - e associe o valor do form a ele.

```
export class Game{
  public nome: string;      

  public constructor(init?: Partial<Game>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}

onSubmit(form) {
         Game game = new Game(form.value);
         this.http.post<Game>('http://localhost:5000/api/games', game, this.options)
         .subscribe(dados => Console.log(dados));
}
```

Se o objeto for valido você poderá receber ele adequadamente no serviço da seguinte forma.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Game game)
{
    if(game != null)
    {
       GameDAO.Insert(game.nome);
    }
}
```

O adequado quando for realizar uma pergunta é inserir o trecho de código pois auxilia bastante nas repostas.